# Uploading media to AWS from Parse

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, parse-platform, amazon-elastic-transcoder

I built an API with Node that allows users to upload data and media (photo or video).
I already have everything set up with AWS to store the media and covert it from an mp4 to something streamable.

After I built a lot of the API, I decided that it would be best to just use parse.

Since I obviously don't want to store media files with parse, is there a way to store data about the media from the normal POST request (location, description, tags, user_id, created_date....) in Parse, but have Parse send the media file off to AWS, and then also tell AWS to kick off an Elastic Transcoder job?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Parse Cloud Code Webhooks](https://parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#cloud-code-advanced-cloud-code-webhooks) to achieve this. Below are a few related posts for high-level description and an available demo which connects with Heroku, but it should be similar to connect with AWS -- Heroku is hosted on AWS afterall :)

[Introducing Cloud Code Webhooks](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/introducing-cloud-code-webhooks/)

> With this, you can now specify any URL to receive a POST in response
>   to triggers like beforeSave and afterSave on objects, as well as when
>   a Cloud Function is called. You now have the freedom to write code in
>   whatever language you want. As long as you have a server running it,
>   your Cloud Code can integrate with it.

[Parse with Heroku](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/introducing-heroku-parse/)

> One powerful feature of Parse is Webhooks, which lets you connect your
>   Parse app to any server on the web to use a custom server environment
>   rather than Parse’s hosted Cloud Code. We’re always looking for ways to make 
>   Parse easier to use, and recently, we released Node.js middleware to
>   make it easier to connect your Parse app to a Node.js server.
>
> Today we’re excited to announce that we’re partnering with Heroku to
>   make it even easier to connect your Parse app to Node.js code. If you
>   like Parse’s Cloud Code but wish you had a full Node.js environment,
>   this is a great solution. We’ve created a smooth experience for you to
>   run code on either Heroku or the Parse Cloud and we’re very excited
>   about the opportunities this combination has to offer.